# Prevent pass props from child to parent in styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, inheritance, styled-components

I am using styled components library with TypeScript. I have issue when I create styled component `B` that inherits from react component `A`. `A` is node_module (I cannot change behavior of `A`). But `A` pass all props to `div`.

If `B` has any prop that `A` doesn't have, warning message shows in console, because `div` has no attribute `isExpanded`:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `isExpanded` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `isexpanded` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

```
interface AProps {

}

interface BProps {
    isExpanded: boolean
}

const A = (props: AProps) => (
    <div {...props} />
) // Component A pass all props to <div>

const B = Styled(A)<BProps>`

` // I need isExpaned prop in component B and I would like to interit from A
```

Is there any way to prevent "bubble" props from child to parent in styled component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no build-in solution for this in styled components, but you can wrap it into a function component and destructure the unwanted properties.

```
const B = Styled(({isExpanded, ...props})=><A {...props}/>)<BProps>`
```

You can also have a look at the github-issue about this topic: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/135